# Python: Drawing bisector between two points in L1 and L∞ metric

Tags: python, matplotlib, geometry, metric

I am trying to write a program in Python to draw the bisectors between two points in L1 and L∞ metric. Please find more information about the metrics [here](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/m125a/intro_analysis_ch7.pdf). If (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) are the two points, then I feel the equation of the bisector in L1 metric should be:

```
|x-x1|+|y-y1| = |x-x2| + |y-y2|
```

In the L∞, I feel the equation should be:

```
max(|x-x1|,|y-y1|) = max(|x-x2|,|y-y2|)
```

If absolute values were not part of the equation, I would have simplified it to a form y=ax+b and plotted the values of (x,y) over a range of x. Can you please guide me in transforming this into code?

Comment: Have you explored the problem a bit by drawing with paper and pencil?

Comment: Yes, I have. Some examples are also available [here](http://yaroslavvb.com/papers/tan-voronoi.pdf). It felt unintuitive initially since I am used to Euclidean but with a graph sheet, it didn't seem difficult. My main concern is converting the abs(y-y1) and abs(y-y2) to get an equation in terms of y.

Comment: In some cases, there are many y values corresponding to one x value.

Comment: That's correct. It could be the other way round too since bisectors are polygonal chains and not just straight lines anymore.

Comment: Yes, but only the first case prevents you from plotting y as a function of x.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Thank you. Any hint/pointers at proceeding further?

Comment: At this point, I don't know what the problem is. You know enough to implement something.